# Why <Link/> does not working even after implementing solution from react-router-dom docs?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, react-router-dom, react-router-redux

I have tried everything finded at google. For example [from docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/redux-integration)
 I tried add withRouter. Btw my problem component did not have `connect()`.

[App.js]
`<Route path="/companies" component={LazyCompany} />`

[Company component]

```
<Route
  exact
  path="/companies/:companyId"
  render={
    () => {
      if (checkPermissions(currentUser, 'companies', 'read')) {
        return <EditCompany />;
      }
      return <PermissionError />;
    }}
/>
```

[Problem component with Link]
`<Link to="/companies/1">some link</Link>`

[Parent of my problem component (not Company or App)]
`case CALL: return (<CallDetails call={activity} />);`

The Link is clickable, and address in browser changing but the new page did not render. I am using `react-router-redux` package

Comment: What exactly is the problem with `Link`? Does clicking it just not do anything? Is there an error message that pops up when you click?

Comment: @idtcoop thank you for your response. The Link is clickable, and address in browser changing but the new page did not render. I am using `react-router-redux` package